# My paint bucket tool is pouring patterns instead of a block colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm having a really weird problem with my paint bucket.  It is pouring out a weird pattern, I have no idea how this has happened or how to undo it.  Any advice would be really appreciated, thanks.

[image: Burger with weird pattern fill.]

Comment: In the `Paint bucket tool` options ( Since I can't see it in your screenshot, it can be activated here: `Window > options`) select `Foreground` instead of `Pattern`. It's the second dropdown list in there. It is probably saying `Pattern` at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the top left of your screen when you have the paint bucket selected. You should see a dropdown that allows you to switch between **Foreground** and **Pattern**.

[image]

Comment: Hi Kelly, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!